# iOS - USB audio doesn't work at all when AVAudioSession is in playAndRecord category

Tags: ios, audio, avaudiosession

I have an iOS app, written in Swift, that uses audio input and output (actually an AI chatting app). It works fine when using the built-in speaker and microphone, and also when plugging in headphones, but audio stops working when I plug in a USB audio mixer, which has it's own speakers and microphone.

I've found if I set the category of the `AVAudioSession` to `AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord` the mic works. Similarly, if I set the category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` the speaker works. But when I try `AVAudioCategoryPlayAndRecord` nothing from the USB audio works - the app behaves as if there's no USB audio device attached.

Am I missing something here, or is this just the way it is? That this port can only be used for input or output, but not both?

Comment: I am also having this issue, have you found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to solve this. In my situation, I didn't actually need recording and playback at the same time, so wrote code to tear down and then re-activate a new audio session each time the app switched between recording and playback. Not a great outcome, and it's kind of flaky, but there you go.